# How to check what exact windows git credential manager is in effect?

Tags: git

I am using git on windows.

The command `>git config --get credential.helper` returns `manager`.

I need to know what exact manager is in effect.

The reason I am asking is that I know there are a few options for git credential manager on windows, including but not limited to the following:

- This older and archive project: https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows
- More recent multi-platform credential manager:  https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core
- I know there are more options ...

How can I get more detail on what exact credential manager affects my git installation on windows?

Comment: how many accounts do you have set up on this machine? Did you check the basic option of Windows Credential Manager for git credentials? Maybe I'm not getting _why_ you need this.

Comment: Git just runs `git-credential-<name>`, so whatever binary or script turns up when Git tries to run that, is the manager. Note that this violates the usual `git foo-bar` pattern by using `git-foo-bar`, but usually it's looking in the back end directory whose name is printed by running `git --exec-path`, so that's where you'd probably find this program.